# Flutter & Dart SQL Lite package: Is it possible to execute multiple Update statements in ONE query (different whereArg each time)

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I'm thinking about making my SQL query more efficient.
One query statement instead of using a for-loop and spamming the DB with the same query and different values.
Take a look at what I'm doing here and please check if it's possible to make this more efficient.
From what I understand, you can have multiple values in a map that have the same value, but you cannot have more than one key that is the same. Hence my dilemma.

```
Future<void> updateAllGoalsFollowingReorder(
      List<Goal> newGoalTileList) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();

    for (var goal in newGoalTileList) {
      var response = await db.update(
          _goalsTable,
          {
            'goalIndexForDb': goal.goalIndexForDb,
          },
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [goal.id]);
      print(response);
    }
  }
```

I've tried creating a list of goal ids to place in the whereArgs. But for the map: `{ 'goalIndexForDb': goal.goalIndexForDb, },` I obviously cannot have the same key for each value. Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `batch update` to do this type of work. Something like this code,

```dart
Future<void> updateAllGoalsFollowingReorder(List<Goal> newGoalTileList) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    var batch = db.batch();

    for (var goal in newGoalTileList) {
        batch.update(
            _goalsTable,
            {'goalIndexForDb': goal.goalIndexForDb},
            where: 'id = ?',
            whereArgs: [goal.id]
        );
    }

    var responses = await batch.commit();
    print(responses);
}
```

**reference:**

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#batch-support

Comment: Lovely! And wow, right there in the documentation of the package. Thank you for this and forgive me for not looking through the docs for this.

Comment: You’re very welcome! There’s no need to apologize. It’s completely normal not to remember every detail in the documentation.